# Is there something like malloc/free in java?

Tags: java, memory-management

I've never seen such statements though,does it exist in java world at all?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Java's version of `malloc` is `new` -- it creates a new object of a specified type.

In Java, memory is managed for you, so you cannot explicitly `delete` or `free` an object.

Comment: So I can't access the memory space directly?

Comment: No, you cannot gain access to the underlying pointer/memory address of a Java object through any sane means. C# allows you to do this using the `unsafe` keyword:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8(v=VS.100).aspx

Please note that this is very, very rarely necessary.

Comment: Referencing the object you want to free to null tells the garbage collector memory if free to collect.

Answer (score 5):

Java has a garbage collector. That's why you never see such statements in your code(which is nice if you ask me)

> In computer science, garbage
>   collection (GC) is a form of automatic
>   memory management. It is a special
>   case of resource management, in which
>   the limited resource being managed is
>   memory. The garbage collector, or just
>   collector, attempts to reclaim
>   garbage, or memory occupied by objects
>   that are no longer in use by the
>   program. Garbage collection was
>   invented by John McCarthy around 1959
>   to solve problems in Lisp.

Answer (score 4):

`new` instead of `malloc`, garbage collector instead of free.

Answer (score 4):

No direct equivalents exist in Java:

C `malloc` creates an untyped heap node and returns you a pointer to it that allows you to access the memory however you want.

Java does not have the concept of an untyped object, and does not allow you to access memory directly.  The closest that you can get in Java to `malloc` would be `new byte[size]`, but that returns you a strongly typed object that you can ONLY use as a byte array.

C `free` releases a heap node.

Java does not allow you to explicitly release objects.  Object deallocation in Java is totally in the hands of the garbage collector.  In some cases you can influence the behaviour of the GC; e.g. by assigning `null` to a reference variable and calling `System.gc()`.  However, this does not force the object to be deallocated ... and is a very expensive way to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

If you are up to no good (tm) I suppose you can get access to raw memory though the JNI interface.  This is where you can call C programs from Java Programs.  Of course you have to be running in an environment where your program has the privileges to do so (a browser won't normally allow this unless it is suicidal) but you can access objects via C pointers that way.

I sort of wonder where the original question is coming from.  At one point long ago I was totally skeptical of the notion that C-style memory management and C-style pointers were not needed, but at this point I am true believer.

Comment: +1 For pointing out JNI -- not that this will automagically allow access to object management, but using JNI one can deal with "unmanaged" memory/resources if they so choose.