# How can I make a malloc in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have to make a memory manager using cellphones like nodes that provides memory. I need to know how can I request memory and return that direction of memory.

Comment: take a look into ndk,you do your c,c++ stuff using ndk with android

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4404894/5291413